# Select case mess in JFreeChart

Tags: sql, oracle, jfreechart

I have a Column(cliente_x_hora, a numeric field) i put in a interval and count the number in each interval.I have 3 textfields(number of intervals,value between intervals and initial value). When I select the two first(with 5 intervals and 1000 value), the query run flawless and generate the expect barchart.

Query(with two select textfields):

```
SELECT INTERVAL, COUNT(*) TOTAL FROM (  
SELECT CASE WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>0 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=1000.00 THEN '0<CLIENTE_X_HORA>  <=1000.00'   
WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>1000.00 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=2000.00 THEN '1000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA><=2000.00'   
WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>2000.00 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=3000.00 THEN '2000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA><=3000.00'   
WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>3000.00 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=4000.00 THEN '3000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA><=4000.00'   
ELSE '4000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA'  END   INTERVAL, CLIENTE_X_HORA  FROM SGD_CAUSA)  
GROUP BY INTERVAL ORDER BY TOTAL
```

The barchart is [image: here]

The problem is when I select the last field(initial value with, per example 2000), my barchart go crazy(i believe is adding up the discarded values below 2000):
[image: http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/5025/querycom5intervalo1000v.png]

That `ELSE(>6000)` should be much smaller than is showing.How can I solve that?

Best Regards,
  DDias

**CLARIFICATION from OP**:

The query is the same as above but begins in 2000:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>2000 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=3000.00... and ends in 6000:ELSE '6000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA' END INTERVAL, CLIENTE_X_HORA FROM SGD_CAUSA) GROUP BY INTERVAL ORDER BY TOTAL
```

put the result in table form is impractical(we are talking about over 87 thousand rows) **That happens always when i give an initial value different than ZERO**.

Comment: (1) Please show **the exact query** that exhibits this *"crazy"* behavior and **its result** in table form.

Comment: The query is the same as above but begins in 2000:SELECT CASE WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>2000 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=3000.00... and ends in 6000:ELSE '6000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA'  END   INTERVAL, CLIENTE_X_HORA  FROM SGD_CAUSA)  GROUP BY INTERVAL ORDER BY TOTAL     put the result in table form is impractical(we are talking about over 87thousand rows)  That happens always when i give an initial value different than ZERO. BestRegards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ELSE` is just that. It includes **everything** that is not matched by specific `WHEN`s.

So if you do not start from zero, that last column will include everything below a lowest limit in addition to greater than highest limit.

So if you do not want this behavior, do **not** use `ELSE` at all. Use `WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA > 6000.00` (or whatever your highest limit is) as the **last** condition.

**EDIT:**

1. In your internal query filter out (with `WHERE`) the values that are below the lowest limit.
2. Since we no longer have unneeded low range, you no longer need the `HAVING` clause we added and you can even go back to using `ELSE`.
3. If your lowest limit is zero, then you will be filtering everything below 0, which I assume is nothing.

Comment: I replaced my last query from:
"ELSE "+"'"+maxValue+"<"+selected_field+"' ";
To:
"WHEN "+selected_field+">"+maxValue+" THEN '"+maxValue+"<"+selected_field+"'"
But it gives me that ERROR: 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null 'key' argument.

Comment: What we have now is that all lower values are now grouped under `NULL` key.  We need to exclude them before they get to `JFreeChart`.  Please add `HAVING INTERVAL IS NOT NULL` after `GROUP BY`.

Comment: PM 77-1, i am having another wierd behaviour after buting HAVING... in my QUERY: without initial value(initial is 0):http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/1261/with5and1000with0initia.png    with 2000 as initial value: http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/5144/with5and1000with2000ini.png  should be much bigger than is showing after value>4000

Comment: Another option is to exclude lower range in the *internal* sub-query using `WHERE CLIENTE_X_HORA < 2000.00`; this way `COUNT` will be calculated w/o lower range.

Comment: Where i will put that WHERE clause? Thanks for your help. Best Regards,

Comment: Right after `FROM SGD_CAUSA` and before the closing bracket `)`.

Comment: PM 77-1, didn t work fine: http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/5688/wherelower2000.png   It must show the five intervals choosen by the user.

Comment: I'm having difficulty opening your images.  Please see the edit in my answer. Let me know if it solves your problems.

Comment: I tried: SELECT INTERVAL, COUNT(*) TOTAL FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>2000.00 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=3000.00 THEN '2000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA<=3000.00' WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>3000.00 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=4000.00 THEN '3000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA<=4000.00' WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>4000.00 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=5000.00 THEN '4000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA<=5000.00' WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>5000.00 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=6000.00 THEN '5000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA<=6000.00' WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>6000.00 THEN '6000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA' END INTERVAL, CLIENTE_X_HORA  FROM SGD_CAUSA WHERE CLIENTE_X_HORA<2000.00)

Comment: GROUP BY INTERVAL HAVING INTERVAL IS NOT NULL ORDER BY TOTAL but i receive a blank screen in JFreeChart. If i skipp HAVING INTERNAL, i receive the Null 'key' argument ERROR.

Comment: You need to decide where the lowest limit belongs.  In your sample, you need **either** `CASE WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA >= 2000.00` **or**  `WHERE CLIENTE_X_HORA <= 2000.00`. One (and only one) of the conditions should include equality.

Comment: skipping WHERE clause i have:SELECT INTERVAL, COUNT(*) TOTAL FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>2000.00 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=3000.00 THEN '2000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA<=3000.00' WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>3000.00 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=4000.00 THEN '3000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA<=4000.00' WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>4000.00 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=5000.00 THEN '4000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA<=5000.00' WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>5000.00 AND CLIENTE_X_HORA<=6000.00 THEN '5000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA<=6000.00' WHEN CLIENTE_X_HORA>6000.00 THEN '6000.00<CLIENTE_X_HORA' END   INTERVAL, CLIENTE_X_HORA  FROM SGD_CAUSA)

Comment: GROUP BY INTERVAL HAVING INTERVAL IS NOT NULL ORDER BY TOTAL but that broughts bar when cliente_x_hora>6000 with only 216 what is totally fake(compares with the first bar with begins in 0).

Comment: May be I was unclear. You do need `WHERE' clause. Just use it as `WHERE ... <= 2000.00` (less **or equal**). Then you will not need `HAVING` (or so I think).

Comment: PM 77-1, even using <=2000, it needs HAVING clause(gives null error without), and even with that, dont return ANY value(using less or equal).I changed to WHERE CLIENTE_X_HORA>2000.00 and strangely, all the numbers in each bar are very LOW: between 5000 and 6000=113, between 4000 and 5000=217 and bigger than 6000=216... i odnt know where is my mistake.Without choosing initial value is fine.that s strange.

Comment: Something is wrong here. Do you have access to `SQL Developer` or `SQL Plus`? Can you run your query directly in `Oracle` (not through `JDBC`)?  I mean - just the SQL part.

Comment: PM 77-1 i post the sqlcode(with pictures in last post) here: http://www.guj.com.br/java/299531-queryoracle-para-jfreechart first picture is with initialvalue equal to 2000, last picture is with initial value equal 0.I will run SQL Plus and post results here.Wait a little bit.

Comment: PM 77-1, thanks for your help!The problem was with my ELSE.I never learned even negative values can go to my ELSE value.My query(with last value):FROM SGD_CAUSA WHERE CLIENTE_X_HORA>2000.00)  GROUP BY INTERVAL HAVING INTERVAL IS NOT NULL ORDER BY TOTAL is correct!My Main query with ELSE was INCORRECT!